# Search for reverse dependencies with versioned depends

Tags: r, rcpp, cran

Is there any way to search for installed packages that depend on a particular version of another package? The `dependsOnPkgs` function from `tools` does not seem to support this.

I would like to find all packages on CRAN that depend/import/link `Rcpp >= 0.11`, such as currently [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html) and [httpuv](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httpuv/index.html). I need this information to "pin" these packages to an older version that worked with `Rcpp 0.10.6`, until I can upgrade `Rcpp` on my servers.

Comment: To a first approximation ALL of CRAN that uses Rcpp uses Rcpp (>= 0.11.0).  I did fairly extensive tests prior to uploading that version (at the request of CRAN). So they were ALL rebuilt (on Windows), and can all be rebuilt.  And in this case, must be rebuilt.  So in sum, I think you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: Ie the other packages that do not list 'Rcpp (>= 0.11.0)' still work with Rcpp, but also require a rebuilt -- the 0.11.0 release had an architectural change which does require rebuilds. [ And yes, I am in the process of doing that on several work servers too ... ]

Comment: I cannot push `r-cran-rcpp 0.11` to stable/production branches at this point because, as you explained, it causes currently installed packages to break. So for these branches I will have to avoid package versions that require `Rcpp >= 0.11`.

Comment: @Jeroen perhaps this can help you. https://github.com/hadley/cran-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment above helps a little to clarify.

What you need to do is to use something like [this script on GitHub](https://github.com/RcppCore/rcpp-logs/blob/master/scripts/showReverseRcppDepends.r) which identifies your installed and Rcpp-using packages, and splits it between those from CRAN and elsewhere.

Those from CRAN you can rebuild with a single R command; the others you need to hunt down.

We are sorry for the inconvenience caused, but there is no other way around it. The 0.11.* release series requires a rebuild.  All CRAN packages are expected to pass; you just need to spend the few minutes compiling them. If your servers are running the same OS configuration, you can then simply rsync the package directory to the other machines.